# Low Memory throughput in Linux-Embedded ( ARM )

Tags: linux, embedded, arm

I am using ARM926EJS. I am getting 20 % more memory speed in memory copy test, without Linux ( Just as a Getting Started executable). But in linux same code is running 20% slower.

Code is

```
 
/// Below code just performs burst mode memcopy test.        
void asmcpy(void *a, void *b, int iSize)
{
   do
  {
    asm volatile (
             "ldmia %0!, {r3-r10} \n\t"
             "stmia %0!, {r3-r10} \n\t"
             :"+r"(a), "+r"(b)
             :
             :"r"(r3),"r"(r4),"r"(r5),"r"(r6),"r"(r7),"r"(r8),"r"(r9),"r"(r10)
             );
  }while(size--)
}
```

I verified that no other process is taking CPU time on linux.( I checked this with the use of time command, It shows **real time** is same as  **usr time**)

Please tell me what can be the problem with linux?

Thanks & Regards.

ADDED:

my test code is

```
int main()
{
  int a[320 * 120], b[320 * 120];

 for(int i=0; i != 10000; i++)
 {
   /// Size is divided by 8 because our memcpy function performs 8 integer load stores in the iteration
   asmcpy(a, b, (320 * 120) / 8);
 }
}
```

Getting Started executable is a bin file which is sent to the RAM using serial port and executes directly by jumping to that address in RAM. (without the need of an OS)

ADDED.

I haven't seen such performance difference on other processors.They were using SD RAM, This processor is using DDR Ram. Can it be a reason?

ADDED.
  Data Cache is not enabled in getting started code and Data Cache is eabled in Linux mode, So Ideally all data should be cached and get accessed without any RAM latency, But still Linux is 20% slow.

ADDED:
  My microcontroller is LPC3250. Both the test are been tested on same external DDR RAM.

Comment: can you post your testing code and scenario on the two different setups? Also what is Getting Started executable? Just a little more elaboration in general there could be a lot of different reasons

Comment: it's almost apples to oranges performance comparison here since youre running with a complete operating system which has timer ticks, memory management, etc which all is scheduled to run vs no operating system just running the straight instructions. I think that pretty much explains your performance difference. Like javier said even though theres no other user processes going on the kernel still does alot by itself.

Comment: I have a similar hardware (ARM926EJS + DDR) and I observe quite the opposite : memory operations is sooo slow without OS, until Cache is activated (ie in the OS)

Comment: Use Burst Mode RAM access as I am doing, Use LDMIA and STMIA to increase your speed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This chip has an MMU, so Linux is likely using it to manage memory.  Maybe just enabling it introduces some performance hit.  Also, Linux uses a lazy memory allocation strategy, only assigning memory pages to a process when it first hits it.  If you're copying a big chunk of memory, the MMU will generate page faults to ask the kernel to allocate a page while inside your loop.  On a low-end processor, all these context switches cause cache flushes and introduce a noticeable slowdown.

If your system is small enough, try an MMU-less version of Linux (like [uClinux](http://www.uclinux.org/)).  Maybe it would let you use a cheaper chip with similar performance.  On embedded systems, every penny counts.

**update:** Some extra details:

Every Linux process gets it's own memory mappings, At first this include only the kernel and (maybe) executable code.  All the rest of the linear 4GB (on 32bit) seems available, but there's no RAM pages assigned to them.  As soon as you read or write an unallocated memory address, the MMU signals a page fault and switches to the kernel.  The kernel sees that it still has lots of free RAM pages, so picks one, assigns it to the faulted point and returns to your code, which finishes the interrupted instruction.  The very next one won't fail because the whole page (typically 4KB) is already assigned; but a few iterations later, it will hit another non-assigned space, and the MMU will invoke the kernel again.

Comment: HI Javier, I am doing mem copy from ram to ram only. So How page fault can happen? I am doing memcopy with 153KB memory allocated on stack. I am running it in loop for 10,000 times.

Comment: All RAM is memory-managed, so a fault can happen any time. see update.

Comment: Hum... 300KB is just a few pages, and after the first one, all that space should be mapped, so you shouldn't get faults anymore.  As mentioned above, some simplistic MMUs introduce another step on the processing pipeline and might affect performance just because they're active, even if not generating faults anymore.

Comment: Another issue, even you say 'no other process is taking CPU time', you always have the timer ticks and a handful of kernel threads.  Check /proc/<pid>/stat for some insight on where the time is going

Answer (score 3):

How are you performing the timing? There is no timing code in your example.

Are you sure that you are not measuring process load/unload time?

Is the processor clock speed the same in both cases?

If using external SDRAM are the RAM timings the same in both cases?

Is the data cache enabled in both cases?

Clifford

Comment: Is the "time" syscommand returning the right numbers?  It might be misconfigured.  When you get weird results like this, a good option is to have the program print out a couple of things a minute apart according to its timer, and time them with a physical clock (or stopwatch).

Comment: Data Cache is disabled on Getting stated mode. Will use Stopwatch and let you know, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Getting started is not "just an executable". There must be some code to set the DDR controller register.

If cache is also enabled, then so must be the MMU. I think on ARM926EJS, you can't have data cache without MMU.

I believe every context switch results in a cache flush, because the cache is virtually indexed, virtually tagged and Kernel and Userspace don't share the same address space, so you probably have a lot more unwanted cache flush in the than without OS.

Here is a [paper](http://opensrc.sec.samsung.com/document/uc-linux-04_sait.pdf) with some aspect on the cost of VIVT cache flush when running Linux

Answer (score 1):

What microcontroller (not just what ARM CPU) are you using?

Is it possible that in the non-Linux run the array you're testing is RAM on the microcontroller device itself while in the Linux test the array being tested is in external RAM? Internal RAM is usually accessed much faster than external RAM - this might account for the Linux test being slower, even if data caching is enabled only for the Linux run.

Comment: Hi Michael, My microcontroller is LPC3250. Both the data are been tested on same external DDR RAM.